# How to add Postgres support to PHP installed by Homebrew?

Tags: php, mac-osx

I have already installed and configured new version of PHP with Homebrew, including MySQL support and XDebug. That works fine. However, I need to install the support for PostgreSQL as well. How can I do it?

I have figured out it is easy when installing PHP for the first time, just by adding the option:

```
homebrew install php53 --with-pgsql
```

How can I achieve something similar when my PHP is already installed, without reinstalling it completely? Or, if I reinstall, are all configs and additional settings, such as XDebug, kept?

Comment: The same applies for --with-mysql, I guess...

Answer (score 23):

`brew help` does not show every option available. To get more details about all of the available commands, see `man brew`. In your case, you can run the reinstall command:

```
brew reinstall php53 --with-postgresql
```

According to the brew man page, this is synonymous with running uninstall and then install. It does appear that brew will back up known configuration files first.

If brew complains about not being able to find `pg_config`, then that means you need to install `postgresql` first -- it has to be `postgresql`; otherwise it'll never find `pg_config`. I spent an inordinate amount of time trying to figure out why `--with-pgsql` wouldn't work when I had the `postgresql92` formulae installed.

I can personally confirm that it will not remove any custom configuration files.

Comment: --with-pgsql is deprecated. Use --with-postgresql

Comment: This definitely worked for me!

Answer (score 15):

When php is already installed, you can just run `brew install php55-pdo-pgsql`

Comment: this is for the pdo driver only, not the pgsql extension

Answer (score 3):

If you use Homebrew:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/|grep php
php54
```

As you can see my homebrew version is for PHP 5.4, so I search Homebrew with:

`brew search php54`

In the search results, I see `php54-pdo-pgsql`.

So, I install the driver with:

`brew install php54-pdo-pgsql`

Then restart PHP.

Answer (score 3):

Thy Following on Mac OS X if you already have php installed.

```
brew install homebrew/php/php55-pdo-pgsql
```

Comment: I don't see how that is substantially different from earlier answers.

Comment: Above commands didn't work for me this worked.

Answer (score 2):

If you did install php with brew, you have to restart the php after you install any module:

```
brew services restart php70
```

after that you can use the new installed module.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with PHP55 and solved it with uninstalling (brew uninstall php55) and reinstalling (brew install php55 --with-postgresql ).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above answers, though none of those worked quite well enough in my case, I used `brew reinstall php70 --with-postgresql` rather than un/install, which failed because of linked dependencies.

Follow that with `brew services restart php70` as suggested above, and `sudo apachectl restart` for good measure.