# Adding IMAP support to brew php after install

Tags: php, mac-osx

Possibly related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/533103/how-to-add-postgres-support-to-php-installed-by-homebrew), but I need some clarification.

I'm managing a Mac Mini server with brew's php54 installed. I did not do the install; the developer who did has since left the company. As such, I don't know what extensions php was compiled with, and because the server's in use, I don't want to break it.

Is it possible to install the --with-imap support without losing any current extensions? E.g. if it was run as `brew install php54 --with-mcrypt`, will `brew reinstall php54 --with-imap` remove mcrypt?

If it will lose extensions, is it possible to find what php was compiled with, to recreate the brew install command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
php -m
```

will list modules compiled in (this list is likely longer then what is implied by the following command:

```
brew info php54
```

will show the install options of the current (and previous) installs

Example (with `mutt` instead of `php54`:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mutt/1.6.1 (88 files, 4.7M) *
  Built from source on 2016-05-10 at 16:02:12 with: --with-confirm-attachment-patch --with-gpgme --with-s-lang
```

Use the options listed there and add the one you need.